# How do I handle this htaccess rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that is giving me trouble in terms of a rewrite:

```
http://www.example.com/my-directory/?image=21
```

I have tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /http://www.example.com/my-directory/?image=21 http://www.example.com
```

Or I know that something along these lines is probably on the right path but I dont think I have the rewrite condition quite right:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?image=21)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? What is the input URL and what should be the expected output URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^image=21$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^my-directory/?$ http://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This does work nicely, my only question is what in this command is insuring that other queries containing 'image=21' do not get rewritten? Do we need anything additional to specify it is only when coming from 'my-directory'?

Comment: This rule will only affect `/my-directory/?image=21` but will NOT affect `/some-directory/?image=21`.

Comment: As you can see in `RewriteRule ^my-directory/?$` line. Let me know if I didn't answer your question correctly.

Comment: you absolutely did, I just wanted additional clarification.